# Selenium not showing the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open an url with Selenium, but it is opening only a blank google page

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

cService = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path='C:\\Users\\jmarc\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\chrome-win64\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = cService)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.br/ref=nav_logo")
sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

This code is only opening a blank google page